# Control of pendulum (crane trolley)

Tags: control-systems

I need to control crane trolley (pendulum), I have state space representation as:

$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{m_b}{m_j}g  & 0  \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1  \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{m_b+m_j}{m_j L}g  & 0  \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$

$
 B=\begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\ \frac{1}{m_j} \\ 0 \\ -\frac{1}{m_j L}
 \end{bmatrix}
$

$
 C=\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{bmatrix}
$

$
 D=\begin{bmatrix}
 0
 \end{bmatrix}
$

I have been told that if I want to use state feedback, I need to extend this system with integrator. Why?

(I could provide any other possible information, just ask in comment)

Comment: you probably wanna track the error between reference and measured signal, that's why you'd need an integral action. At the end, your step response is gonna show zero-error in steady conditions.

Comment: It is obvious now, that you are correct! You can create answer, I will accept it.